# C - MPI text file open

Tags: c, file, mpi

Hi guys I am learning to program in MPI and I came across this question. Lets say I have a .txt file with 3 000 000 rows/lines with text(It's a dictionary) so it will be string of array, how do I chunk them for processing by 4 processors? i.e. I want to let processor 0 take care of the processing for lines 1-750 000, processor 1 to take care of 750 001-1 500 000 and so on. Then each process take part of data and put into a function to e.g. find_some_word.

Now I get this but I don't know how to get a single word for rank from my chunk. This part is commented in program, how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>

bool if_anagram(char *a, char *b)
{

    int dl1 = strlen(a), dl2 = strlen(b);


    if(dl1!=dl2) return false;
    if(strcmp(a,b) == 0) return false;

    int licz[0x100]={}; 

    for(int i=0;i<dl1;i++)    
        licz[(unsigned char) a[i]]++; 
    for(int i=0;i<dl1;i++)
        licz[(unsigned char) b[i]]--;       
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)      
        if(licz[i]!=0) 
            return false; 

  return true; 
} 

void parprocess(MPI_File *in, char *a, const int rank, const int size, const int overlap) {

    MPI_Offset globalstart;
    int mysize;
    char *chunk;

    /* read in relevant chunk of file into "chunk",
     * which starts at location in the file globalstart
     * and has size mysize 
     */
    {
        MPI_Offset globalend;
        MPI_Offset filesize;

        /* figure out who reads what */
        MPI_File_get_size(*in, &filesize);
        filesize--;  /* get rid of text file eof */
        mysize = filesize/size;
        globalstart = rank * mysize;
        globalend   = globalstart + mysize - 1;
        if (rank == size-1) globalend = filesize-1;

        /* add overlap to the end of everyone's chunk except last proc... */
        if (rank != size-1)
            globalend += overlap;

        mysize =  globalend - globalstart + 1;

        /* allocate memory */
        chunk = malloc( (mysize + 1)*sizeof(char));

        /* everyone reads in their part */
        MPI_File_read_at_all(*in, globalstart, chunk, mysize, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        chunk[mysize] = '\0';
    }


    /*
     * everyone calculate what their start and end *really* are by going 
     * from the first newline after start to the first newline after the
     * overlap region starts (eg, after end - overlap + 1)
     */

    int locstart=0, locend=mysize-1;
    if (rank != 0) {
        while(chunk[locstart] != '\n') locstart++;
        locstart++;
    }
    if (rank != size-1) {
        locend-=overlap;
        while(chunk[locend] != '\n') locend++;
    }
    mysize = locend-locstart+1;

    /* "Process" our chunk by replacing non-space characters with '1' for
     * rank 1, '2' for rank 2, etc... 
     */

    char b[101];
    for (int i=locstart; i<=locend; i++) {
                                                // THIS PART
        //fscanf (chunk,"%s",b);                // how get a single word from chunk
        //if(if_anagram(a,b)){
            //printf("Word %s is anagram!\n", b);

    //  It is orginal part  
    //    char c = chunk[i];
     //   chunk[i] = ( isspace(c) ? c : '1' + (char)rank );
    //    printf("Wyraz %d\n", rank);
        }
    //}

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_File in;
    int rank, size;
    int ierr;
    const int overlap = 100;
    char a[101];


    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (argc != 2) {
        if (rank == 0) fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infilename\n", argv[0]);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    ierr = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &in);
    if (ierr) {
        if (rank == 0) fprintf(stderr, "%s: Couldn't open file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(2);
    }

        printf("Put word: ");
        scanf ("%s", a);
    printf("\n");

    parprocess(&in, a, rank, size, overlap);


    MPI_File_close(&in);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `MPI_Scatter`. Beyond that - this seems like a tutorial question which is not suitable for SO (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok, but before that I need to load this data to array. If I try do this array will be to small for to many data

Comment: Does your `txt` file has a fixed format (e.g. constant line size) ? If not, MPI-IO is helpless here. Do you at least know how many lines your file contains before reading it ? if both no, and an option would be to have all tasks read all the file (e.g. read all lines) but discard some so you data is already scattered. If you have 3 MPI tasks, then task 0 will only analyze lines 0,3,6, ... and discard other lines, task 1 will only analyze lines 1, 4, 7, ... and task 2 will only analyze lines 2, 5, 8, ...

Comment: My file has text format in OEM852(I don't know how check constant line size), if that's what it was about. I know how many lines there is, so I can do that like you write?

Answer (score 0):

A good tutorial on I/O:
https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/documents/13601/900558/MPI-IO-Final.pdf/eea9d7d3-4b81-471c-b244-41498070e35d

Then one have to understand that MPI-IO can-t read the mind of a file :-). It "only" allow a process to skip a portion of the file (in bytes), if you want to skip a given amount of line and each line have different size, you have no other solution than read the entire file to look for the '\n'. MPI-IO is not a magician...

The best solution would be to create (once) a header, which describe where groups of line finish. You could get the count of bytes for each groups of 10'000 lines, then had this as an header in your file. The you will be able to skip some blocks. Evidently do to so you have to read the entire file once...